# Logistic regression vs Random forest vs GBM: equal performance?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, random-forest, boosting

I'm trying to convince my boss that we should consider using machine learning in our field (oncology). We study brain tumours, roughly 90% die within a few years. I wanted to compare the performance of logistic regression, random forest and GBM for classification. My results show that there is no noteworthy difference in their performance. I do recognize that there are inherent flaws to such comparisons; e.g the logistic model could be improved with some interactions and splines (which are better taken care of out of the box by tree-based models).

I would expect to see a difference between these models. What am I doing wrong?

Reproducible example

```
# Load data 
file <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcy5nm01996famo/data.csv?dl=1", header=T, sep=",")
file$outcome <- as.factor(file$outcome)

# Create trainin and test data
smp_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(file))
set.seed(1)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(file)), size = smp_size)
train     <- file[train_ind, ]
test      <- file[-train_ind, ]

# LOGISTIC REGRESSION
glm.model <- glm(outcome=="1" ~ ., family="binomial", data=train); summary(logmod)
glm.prediction <- predict(object=glm.model, newdata=test, type="response")

# RANDOM FOREST
# 5000 trees should be sufficient. I tried more without noting any material difference.
rf.model <- randomForest(outcome=="1" ~ ., ntree=5000, na.action=na.fail, importance=T, keep.forest=T, data=train)
rf.prediction  <- data.frame(predict(object=rf.model, newdata=test, type="prob"))[,2]

# GBM - testing many trees and using cross validation to find optimal number of trees
gbm.test <- gbm(outcome=="1" ~ ., distribution = "bernoulli", n.trees=20000, cv.folds=5, shrinkage=0.01, verbose=F, data=train)
best.iterations <- gbm.perf(gbm.test) # optimal nr of trees = 2981

# New GBM with optimal nr trees
gbm.model <- gbm(outcome=="1" ~ ., distribution = "bernoulli", n.trees=2981, shrinkage=0.01, verbose=F, data=train)
gbm.prediction <- predict(object=gbm.model, newdata=test, type="response", n.trees=best.iterations)


# Set cut-off to 90% probability to classify as "will die"
# I understand that i could use tree votes (for RF, gbm) but I use probability for all models instead
test$glm.class <- ifelse(glm.prediction>0.9, 1, 0)
test$rf.class <- ifelse(rf.prediction>0.9, 1, 0)
test$gbm.class <- ifelse(gbm.prediction>0.9, 1, 0)


library(pROC) #install.packages("pROC)

roc1 <- roc(response=test$outcome, predictor=test$glm.class, percent=T, auc=T, plot=T)
roc2 <- roc(response=test$outcome, predictor=test$rf.class, percent=T, auc=T, plot=T)
roc3 <- roc(response=test$outcome, predictor=test$gbm.class, percent=T, auc=T, plot=T)

auc(roc1)
auc(roc2)
auc(roc3)

library(caret)
sens.glm <- sensitivity(factor(test$glm.class), factor(test$outcome))
spec.glm <- specificity(factor(test$glm.class), factor(test$outcome))

sens.rf <- sensitivity(factor(test$rf.class), factor(test$outcome))
spec.rf <- specificity(factor(test$rf.class), factor(test$outcome))

sens.gbm <- sensitivity(factor(test$gbm.class), factor(test$outcome))
spec.gbm <- specificity(factor(test$gbm.class), factor(test$outcome))
```

Comment: Check out SuperLearner, which is a way of maximizing the performance across several machine learning algorithms. A good introductory article that was written for social scientists is Baćak & Kennedy (2018).

Answer (score 1):

For the ROC and AUC, you should use the probability predictions:

```
roc1 <- roc(response=test$outcome, predictor=glm.prediction, percent=T, auc=T, plot=T)
roc2 <- roc(response=test$outcome, predictor=rf.prediction, percent=T, auc=T, plot=T)

auc(roc1)
auc(roc2)
```

Also make sure that you train a random forest for classification

```
rf.model <- randomForest(outcome ~ ., ntree=500, na.action=na.fail, importance=F, keep.forest=T, data=train)
rf.prediction  <- data.frame(predict(object=rf.model, newdata=test, type="prob"))[,2]
```

The performance is quite similar, (AUC: 90.9 vs 90.78). Depending on the data RF sometimes cannot get much better performance than logistic regression. See here for an interesting comparison: https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/39955/1/TR.pdf

Comment: Many thanks. Will read the paper (seems very good) and follow the advice and get back to you.